# Performing Stemming outputs jibberish/concatenated words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am experimenting with the python library NLTK for Natural Language Processing.

**My Problem:** I'm trying to perform stemming; reduce words to their normalised form. But its not producing correct words. Am I using the stemming class correctly? And how can I get the results I am attempting to get?

I want to normalise the following words:

```
words = ["forgot","forgotten","there's","myself","remuneration"]
```

...into this:

```
words = ["forgot","forgot","there","myself","remunerate"]
```

My code:

```
from nltk import stem
words = ["forgot","forgotten","there's","myself","remuneration"]
for word in words:
    print stemmer.stem(word)

#output is:
#forgot forgotten there' myself remuner
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of normalization you can do at a word level.

1. Stemming - a quick and dirty hack to convert words into some token which is not guaranteed to be an actual word, but generally different forms of the same word should map to the same stemmed token
2. Lemmatization - converting a word into some base form (singular, present tense, etc) which is always a legitimate word on its own. This can obviously be slower and more complicated and is generally not required for a lot of NLP tasks.

You seem to be looking for a lemmatizer instead of a stemmer. Searching Stack Overflow for 'lemmatization' should give you plenty of clues about how to set one of those up. I have played with this one called [morpha](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/morph.html) and have found it to be pretty useful and cool.

Answer (score 1):

Like adi92, I too believe you're looking for lemmatization. Since you're using NLTK you could probably use its [WordNet interface](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html).